# constraining variables on scipy fsolve non linear simultaneous eq

Tags: python, scipy, constraints, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to solve 4 simultaneous non linear equations with 4 unknowns `iL,isat,Rshunt,Rseries` the function first passes variables that are known `iSC,vOC,imax,vmax,Nseries` and then I define my set of functions using `def func1(vars):` my guesses are `9,1e-12,300,0.5` based on physical properties

```
def get_pvparms(iSC,vOC,imax,vmax,Nseries):
    import math as m
    from scipy.optimize import fsolve
    from numpy import sqrt

    n = 1
    boltzmann = 1.3806e-23
    q = 1.60218e-19
    refTemp = 25 + 273.15
    pmax = vmax/imax
    a = n * boltzmann * refTemp * Nseries / q

    def func1(vars):
        iL,isat,Rshunt,Rseries = vars

        iL = iL**2
        isat = isat**2
        Rshunt = Rshunt**2
        Rseries = Rseries**2

        return isat * (m.exp(vOC / a) - 1) + vOC / Rshunt - iL + 0*Rseries,\
               iSC + iSC*Rseries/Rshunt + isat * m.exp(iSC*Rseries/a - 1) - iL,\
               iL - isat*(m.exp((vmax + imax*Rseries)/a)-1) - (vmax + imax*Rseries)/Rshunt - imax,\
               (isat*m.exp((vmax+imax*Rseries)/a)/a + 1/Rshunt)/(1+(isat*Rseries*m.exp((vmax+imax*Rseries)/a)/a)+Rseries/Rshunt) - pmax + 0*iL

    guess = sqrt((iSC,5e-8,300,0.5))

    print fsolve(func1,guess)
```

I get this result

```
 File "C:\Users\Davis_2\Documents\RCL\MAPVsim\pvcalc.py", line 50, in get_pvparms
    print fsolve(func1,guess)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 146, in fsolve
    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 224, in _root_hybr
    ml, mu, epsfcn, factor, diag)
  File "C:\Users\Davis_2\Documents\RCL\MAPVsim\pvcalc.py", line 44, in func1
    iSC + iSC*Rseries/Rshunt + isat * m.exp(iSC*Rseries/a - 1) - iL,\
OverflowError: math range error
```

How can I pass constrains to my guesses? such as values cannot be `negative`?

I attempted to use the squaring method on the variables but i get overflow. Probably implementing it wrong. Any help would be much appreciated

Note: If you take out this piece of code:

```
    iL = iL**2
    isat = isat**2
    Rshunt = Rshunt**2
    Rseries = Rseries**2
```

and take out the sqrt here `guess = sqrt((iSC,5e-8,300,0.5))` it converges to an an answer.

Comment: That's non-trivial code and it's hard to read because of some unobserved imports and co (e.g.: ```sqrt((iSC,5e-8,300,0.5))``` np.sqrt vs. ?). Maybe construct a more simple example with actual data. As some of your inner-workings are only defined for some subset of inputs, you seem to need to prohibit this wrong usage somehow. **A:** use an optimizer which supports constraints (and only constructs feasible iterations) **B:** introduce large penalties for non-defined ranges (more logic needed). But i would be also scared about these possibly huge variable-ranges which can be a problem.